# Opensea testnet not showing metadata

Tags: solidity, erc-721, opensea

Whenever I try to mint something on testnet(rinkeby) Opensea does not show my metadata.

[image]

I use their API and I get validated
https://testnets-api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0x03ecf0f08f96ebe8f25658f9cb3295e7b25fb777/0/validate

I'm also able to see my NFT with correct metadata on rarible and looksrare rinkeby testnets, but not on Opensea, no matter how many times I force metadata refresh from the collection UI or API
https://testnets-api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0x03ecf0f08f96ebe8f25658f9cb3295e7b25fb777/0/?force_update=true

Anyone knows what is happening, is there an issue with opensea or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it just took the opensea testnet more than 24 hours to update the metadata